# How to get Google to unbold URLs in search results

Tags: html

Google adds `<b>` tags to URLs in search results that match parts of the search query. For instance, if `lawyerallen.com` comes up as a search result for Orlando Lawyer, **lawyer** is bolded.

Yesterday, user Adam Buchanan Smith shared the follow script:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll("b")).forEach(function (b) {
    b.parentNode.replaceChild(b.firstChild, b);
});
```

Of course, that took this:

```
<cite class="_Rm">www.<b>lawyer</b>allen.com/</cite>
```

...and made it this:

```
<cite class="_Rm">www.lawyerallen.com/</cite>
```

Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't actually update (as seen under Elements in DevTools) to reflect this change, at least not exactly. See attached image.

[Image of DevTools, before and after code injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4myNB.png)

The end goal here is to get the full URL to display without breaks. No `<b>` tags, no breaks, no anything. The *reason* for this is because I'm using an extension to highlight existing URLs on a list, and it won't find the URL if there are breaks like the ones seen in the attached image. When I modify the code manually in DevTools, the URL highlights perfectly.

Willing to learn and do whatever it takes to get this to work!